# Zend_View_Helper_Partial - performance measure

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, partials, microtime

I am trying to extend the zend partial helper to make it a little faster for my own needs.
The code of how I do that is not important at this point.

I have created a unit test which acts weird and I can not understand the reason for it

this is the code:

```
    $garpTimeStart = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 999; $i++) {
        $this->_createOneGarpView();
    }
    $garpTimeTotal = microtime(true) - $garpTimeStart;

    $zendTimeStart = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 999; $i++) {
        $this->_createOneZendView();
    }
    $zendTimeTotal = microtime(true) - $zendTimeStart;

    $deltaPerformance = $zendTimeTotal - $garpTimeTotal;
    $this->assertTrue($deltaPerformance > 0);
```

ok, basically I create 1000 zendView objects and 1000 of my own garpView objects and I track the time for creating each of these.

Here comes the tricky part:

Simply by switching the order of the creation of the zend and garp views the test will fail.
So, in other words, whichever I create first, will be created faster!
(still, with a obvious difference in performance between the two)

So this in about 4 out of 5 times will fail

```
    $zendTimeStart = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 999; $i++) {
        $this->_createOneZendView();
    }
    $zendTimeTotal = microtime(true) - $zendTimeStart;

    $garpTimeStart = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 999; $i++) {
        $this->_createOneGarpView();
    }
    $garpTimeTotal = microtime(true) - $garpTimeStart;

    $deltaPerformance = $zendTimeTotal - $garpTimeTotal;
    $this->assertTrue($deltaPerformance > 0);
```

What am I missing? how can I create a more suitable environment to test this in?

Comment: Do you have a measurable difference between your code and the zend code? Do you run other stuff on your system/database at the same time of the test?

Comment: of course, I don't run anything else. I thought that the differences in milliseconds are not important...

Comment: It's hard to speculate without seeing the code of the functions you're benchmarking. Do they share any resources/classes which are setup on demand?

Comment: Differences in milliseconds are not important or might be due to other stuff on the computer running (or not running at that moment). And there's always other stuff running an a computer. So you could never be sure. If you run this 1000 times each to have a real increase in performance I would expect a few seconds difference between your "optimized" version and the zend version. If not, your version might not be measurably faster.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind

Comment: Having currently created 1000 objects in memory will decrease your system performance, so having the second 1000 objects created slower is a `normal` behaviour I think. Try `desctructing` the object after creation or try desctructing the first created 1000 objects before creating the second 1000 ones. Do this make sense?